# Binary Search not working in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
def binarysearch(somelist,target):

    lowindex=0
    highindex=len(somelist)-1
    while somelist[lowindex] != target and somelist[highindex] != target:
        midindex = (highindex+lowindex) // 2
        if target == somelist[midindex]:
            print(somelist[midindex])
        elif target < somelist[midindex]:
            highindex=midindex-1
        elif target > somelist[midindex]:
            lowindex= midindex + 1
    return -1

testlist=[0,1,2,8,13,17,19,32,42,15]

(binarysearch(testlist,2))
```

anybody know whats wrong with the code doesnt seem to work

Comment: Your code prints something only if the target is found at `midindex`. If it is found at `lowindex` or `highindex` the `while` loop just stops.

Comment: I assume you are writing your own binary search for the sake of the exercise. If not, then use built-in facilities instead:
`if target in somelist: 
    print(target)
else:
   return -1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: If Element is found then return 1 else -1.

```
def b_search(target):
    somelist = [0,1,2,8,13,17,19,32,42,15]
    lowindex=0 
    highindex=len(somelist)-1
    while lowindex <= highindex:
        midindex = (highindex+lowindex) // 2
        if target == somelist[midindex]:
            return 1
        elif target < somelist[midindex]:
            highindex=midindex-1
        elif target > somelist[midindex]:
            lowindex= midindex + 1
    return -1
print(b_search(11))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your binary search function stalls the `while` loop as soon as the `target` is at first index or the last index in any of the sub-lists formed in the `while` loop.

You just need to check that the low index is always less than or equal to high index and then run the `while` loop. Also, when the element is found, you just print that element and continue the loop. That does not make sense. Either you print and then `break` out of the loop, or simply return the index of the target element if it is found.

So, now your function becomes:

```
def binarysearch(somelist, target):
    lowindex = 0
    highindex = len(somelist) - 1
    while lowindex <= highindex:
        midindex = (highindex+lowindex) // 2
        if target == somelist[midindex]:
            return midindex
        elif target < somelist[midindex]:
            highindex=midindex-1
        elif target > somelist[midindex]:
            lowindex= midindex + 1
    return -1
```

So, now when you run your binary search function, it would return index of element 2 as:

```
[IN]: print(binarysearch(testlist, 2))
[OUT]: 2
```